# What is the difference between machineType and mixedInstancesPolicy

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, kops

Does anybody know when creating InstanceGroup using kops, why we set both `machineType` and `mixedInstancesPolicy`? Does `machineType` means kops will pick `machineType` by default but if no instance with `machineType` available it will pick one of the types from `mixedInstancesPolicy`?

The spec: https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/instance_groups/ shows:
"A Mixed Instances Policy utilizing EC2 Spot and the capacity-optimized allocation strategy allows an EC2 Autoscaling Group to select the instance types with the highest capacity. This reduces the chance of a spot interruption on your instance group."

the spec does not show what `machineType` is and what is the difference of `machineType` and `mixedInstancesPolicy`.

```
apiVersion: kops.k8s.io/v1alpha2
kind: InstanceGroup
...
spec:
  image: kope.io/k8s-1.16-debian-...
  machineType: m5.xlarge
  maxSize: XX
  minSize: XX
  mixedInstancesPolicy:
    instances:
    - m4.xlarge
    - r4.xlarge
    - c4.xlarge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mixedInstancesPolicy` is as described above. `machineType` is used if you do want one specific instance type.

There is a bit of terminology mix-up there. But you can see machineType as the same as instanceType.

If both are set, `mixedInstancesPolicy` is the on that will be used. However, `machineType` must is still validated and must e.g match the architecture of the instances in `mixedInstancesPolicy`.

Comment: Thanks Ole. in fact, my question is: which instance type will be finally selected, the one shown in machineType or those shown in  mixedInstancesPolicy?

Comment: Amended. hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thanks Ole. that means machineType is useless if mixedInstancesPolicy is there? and what does "match the architecture of the instances in mixedInstancesPolicy." mean?

Comment: It means that you cannot use an arm64 instance type mixed with an amd64 instance type. same with GPU vs non-GPU types. And yes, it is sort of useless, but e.g cluster autoscaler requires that it is set in the launch templat.